# Java pattern needed: instantiate object based on class of other object

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

In my app there are objects representing tasks (stored in the DB).
There will also be objects that have the actual implementation of a task (some business logic) - let's call them runners.
So runners could i.e. implement the following interface:

```
public interface Runner<T> {
    void run(T task);
}
```

Given a task object, I need some nice way to create/get a runner so that I can run it.

I'd prefer to avoid something like

```
if(task instance of DoSomethingTask) {
    return new DoSomethingTaskRunner();
} else if(task instance of DoSomethingElseTask) {
    return new DoSomethingElseRunner();
}
```

because then whenever I create a new runner I also need to remember to add another if/else to the above block. It would be nice to just automatically get the runner that implements

```
Runner<myTask.getClass()> // pseudocode ;)
```

A nice way of doing this would be to make the Tasks have a "getRunner" method (adding a new Task I need to implement the method so I cannot forget it) but unfortunately due to project dependencies my Task objects cannot know anything about Runners.

Any ideas regarding how to do it in a nice way?

Btw.: I'm using Spring so it would be even nicer to get a Runner bean based on the passed task.

Comment: how about creating a runner dynamically with Class.forName() ? that way you only need to store the runner class name in the task

Comment: Erm, that's the entire point of the interface. You don't have to know what the concrete class is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow a bean naming convention, for example runnerBeanName = `Task` class name + 'Runner' you could use the `ApplicationContext` as `Runner` factory.

for example:

```
public class RunnerFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Runner getRunner(Task task) {
        return (Runner) applicationContext.getBean(task.getClass().getSimpleName() + "Runner");
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

    }
}
```

You can use alias to bind one runner to many tasks.

If you don't like the factory coupled to Spring, you can also autowire a `Map<String, Runner>` that will be injected with all `Runners` in context by bean name.

Comment: thank you, I'm accepting this answer, because it's simple and whenever I'm adding a new Runner I don't need to change any other classes. I just use something like this: 
@Component(MyTask.class + RUNNER_BEAN_NAME_SUFFIX)
public class MyTaskRunner implements TaskRunner<MyTask> ... This way when I change the name of the task class, the runner bean name will also change automatically :)

Answer (score 4):

You need a RunnerFactory. If you don't want to test the class of the task, you could use the visitor pattern, which allows basically doing what you want (`myTask.createRunner()`), but without any coupling between the task and the runner:

```
public interface TaskVisitor<R> {
    R visitTask1(Task1 task1);
    R visitTask2(Task2 task1);
}

public interface Task {
    // ...
    <R> R accept(TaskVisitor<R> visitor);
}

public class Task1 implements Task {
    // ...
    @Override
    public <R> R accept(TaskVisitor<R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitTask1(this);
    }
}

public class Task2 implements Task {
    // ...
    @Override
    public <R> R accept(TaskVisitor<R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitTask2(this);
    }
}

public class RunnerFactory implements TaskVisitor<Runner> {
    @Override
    public Runner visitTask1(Task1 task1) {
        return new Task1Runner(task1);
    }

    @Override
    public Runner visitTask2(Task1 task2) {
        return new Task2Runner(task2);
    }
}
```

Now, to get a runner from a task, you just need to call

```
RunnerFactory factory = new RunnerFactory();
Runner runner = someTask.accept(factory);
```

And if you add a new Task type, you'll be foced to implement its `accept()` method, which will force you to add a new method to the visitor, and a new Runner implementation.

Comment: thank you, this is an interesting pattern and this answer was quite educational to me. Perhaps I'll use this in the future, but for my current case I think Jose's solution fits my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... make map like:

```
Map<Class<? extends MyTask>, MyRunner> runners;
```

then in xml or @Configuration add mappings. In method `getRunner(Class<? extends MyTask> myTask)` just:

```
 MyRunner getRunner(Class<? extends MyTask> myTask){
    return runners.get(myTask);
 }
```

that's all. Whole 'ifology' now is wrapped by standard map#get

Comment: thanks for your answer, I decided to accept Jose's answer because that way I don't have to update any other classes - all changes in the Runner class.